# How can I link Azure insights/actionGroups to AutomationRunBook

Tags: azure, webhooks, azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template, azure-automation

I'm going around in circles since few days. I would like to link, via ARM Template, my resource "microsoft.insights/actionGroups" to a resource "Microsoft.Automation/automationAccounts/webhooks"

The webhook and the action group are both created via ARM Template. The problem is that when creating the webhook nothing can keep the uri produced by ARM. Then on my resource group the "automationRunbookReceivers" property requests the "serviceUri" parameter which is mandatory. If I refer to my webhook via the resource the uri I get is empty ...

resourceId ('Microsoft.Automation / automationAccounts / webhooks', parameters ('AzureAutomationName'), 'RunBookName')

how could I automate this process?

This is the templates I've used to generate my resources :

```
{
   "name": "[concat(variables('automationAccountName'), '/WebHookName')]",
   "type": "Microsoft.Automation/automationAccounts/webhooks",
   "apiVersion": "2015-10-31",
   "dependsOn": [
      "[concat('Microsoft.Automation/automationAccounts/', variables('automationAccountName'), '/runbooks/', 'RunBookName')]"
   ],
   "properties": {
      "isEnabled": "true",
      "expiryTime": "2026-11-20",
      "runbook": {
         "name": "RunBookName"
      }
   }
},
{
   "name": "[variables('ActionGroupName')]",
   "type": "microsoft.insights/actionGroups",
   "apiVersion": "2019-06-01",
   "location": "Global",
   "tags": {
        "displayName": "ActionGroupName"
   },
   "properties": {
      "groupShortName": "[variables('ActionGroupShortName')]",
      "enabled": true,
      "automationRunbookReceivers": [
         {
            "name": "MyRunBookReceiver",
            "automationAccountId": "[resourceId('microsoft.insights/components', parameters('AzureTelemetryName'))]",
            "runbookName": "RunBookName",
            "webhookResourceId": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Automation/automationAccounts/webhooks', parameters('AzureAutomationName'), 'WebHookName')]",
            "isGlobalRunbook": false,
            "serviceUri": "listCallbackURL? resourceId? reference? other? ?????????"
          }
        ]
     }
  }
```

I desperately need help!

Thank you!

```
[reference(resourceId('Microsoft.Automation/automationAccounts/webhooks', parameters('AzureAutomationName'), 'WebHookName'), '2015-10-31')].uri
```

return empty string

Comment: Can you share the output of the deployment? I think you should add a `depends on` tag in the groups for it to depend on the webhook. This will deploy the webhook first and then the groups.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, we only can see the url of webhook when we create it. You can use Powershell to create it and you can see url of outputs

Comment: Yes you're right with powershell is fine. But not with ARM Template :-(

Answer (score 0):

@bit is correct - the webhook URI is only retrievable at the time of webhook creation and the property is nulled thereafter.  Since you're creating both the actionGroup and the webhook in the same template, though, the deployment happens synchronously and  you can refer to the webhook's URI using its `.uri` property.

The official Microsoft documentation has an example: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-webhooks#create-runbook-and-webhook-with-arm-template

Your ARM template could be modified as follows:

```
{
   "name": "[concat(variables('automationAccountName'), '/WebHookName')]",
   "type": "Microsoft.Automation/automationAccounts/webhooks",
   "apiVersion": "2015-10-31",
   "dependsOn": [
      "[concat('Microsoft.Automation/automationAccounts/', variables('automationAccountName'), '/runbooks/', 'RunBookName')]"
   ],
   "properties": {
      "isEnabled": "true",
      "expiryTime": "2026-11-20",
      "runbook": {
         "name": "RunBookName"
      }
   }
},
{
   "name": "[variables('ActionGroupName')]",
   "type": "microsoft.insights/actionGroups",
   "apiVersion": "2019-06-01",
   "location": "Global",
   "tags": {
        "displayName": "ActionGroupName"
   },
   "properties": {
      "groupShortName": "[variables('ActionGroupShortName')]",
      "enabled": true,
      "automationRunbookReceivers": [
         {
            "name": "MyRunBookReceiver",
            "automationAccountId": "[resourceId('microsoft.insights/components', parameters('AzureTelemetryName'))]",
            "runbookName": "RunBookName",
            "webhookResourceId": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Automation/automationAccounts/webhooks', parameters('AzureAutomationName'), 'WebHookName')]",
            "isGlobalRunbook": false,
            "serviceUri": "[reference(concat(variables('automationAccountName'), '/WebHookName')).uri]"
          }
        ]
     }
  }
```

As an aside, that Microsoft doc uses an `"outputs": { }` object to emit the webhook URI.  That's a really bad idea because the plaintext value of the URI will be recorded in the resource group deployment metadata.  If you need to create the webhook and its clients asynchronously, one solution is to store the webhook URI in a Key Vault secret in the template that creates the webhook, and then consume the Key Vault secret value when deploying the webhook client.